# locust load testing framework is not working aws gpu instance (g4dnxlarge)

Tags: python-3.x, locust

I am trying to run the locust application in one of my AWS gpu instances i.e; **g4dnxlarge** (not working) and I tried the same code in cpu instance in AWS i.e; **m54xlarge**. which is working here

When I initiate the call from the locust UI, it does not hit the API that is running in the AWS instance (g4dnxlarge) and I could successfully hit the API in m54xlarge AWS instance.

I am not sure on why I am facing this issue in **g4dnxlarge** instance where I am not facing this issue in **m54xlarge** instance

Can anyone tell me the issue?

below is the code

```
from locust import HttpUser, task, between

class MyUser(HttpUser):
    wait_time = between(1, 5)  # Adjust wait times as needed

    @task
    def generate_embeddings(self):
        # Define the API endpoint URL
        api_url = "/generate_embeddings"  # Update with your API endpoint

        # JSON payload with input_s3_uri
        payload = {
            "input_s3_uri": "s3://es-pf/images_new",
            "batch_size": 1
        }

        # Send a POST request to the API
        print('api_url: ')
        print(api_url)
        response = self.client.post(api_url, json=payload)

        # Check the response status code
        if response.status_code == 200:
            print("API call successful")
        else:
            print("API call failed with status code:", response.status_code)
```

Error:
[image]

Comment: What do you mean when you say ”it isnt working”? What is the error? My first guess would be a network issue..

Comment: The call from the locust UI is not hitting to the API that is running in the AWS instance

Comment: And what does locust say?

Comment: RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response')

Comment: Then that is your problem :) can you do plain requests (using curl or something) from the host where locust isnt working from? Perhaps your target webserver has a limited range of allowed clients?